# Проблемы с асинхронной функцией getInitialProps, отвечающей за SSR

Tags: reactjs, rest

Я допустил где-то глупую ошибку в коде и у меня не срабатывает асинхронная функция `getInitialProps`.

Вот весь код:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
// import Header from '../components/header'
// import Footer from '../components/footer'

function Contacts({ page: serverPage }) {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(serverPage)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function load() {
      const response = await fetch('http://uer/wp-json/wp/v2/pages')
      const json = await response.json()

      setPage(json)
    }

    if (!serverPage) load()
  }, [])

  if (!page)
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {/* <Header pageName='Contacts' /> */}
        <h2>loading page, please wait...</h2>
        {/* <Footer /> */}
      </React.Fragment>
    )


  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {/* <Header pageName='Contacts' /> */}
      <main dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: page[4].content.rendered }} />
      {/* <Footer /> */}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

Contacts.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
  console.log('help') // Сюда не заходит
  if (!req) return { page: null }

  const response = await fetch('http://uer/wp-json/wp/2/pages/')
  const page = await response.json()

  return page
}

export default Contacts
```

Вообще, моей задачей является выгрузка данные со страницы, выгружаю из коробки WordPress.
На Фронтенд я выгружаю, всё работает прекрасно, однако меня заботит **SSR** и мне нужно его побороть, за него как раз-таки функция `getInitialProps` и отвечает.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.
Функция выполняется, и выполняется при первом переходе на страницу.
А ошибка заключалась в том, что ссылку неверно указал в этой функции.

`/wp/2/pages/` вместо `/wp/v2/pages/`